# For a production platform what is the best way to evaluate the level till which DB should be normalized?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-normalization

For a platform to be deployed for end users, where I have an active user base of more than 100,000 users, what is the best method to decide when I should stop normalizing the DB?
For example:-

`Schema 1:`

Levels_Table=>

- id
- group_id
- reward_given
- level

Level_Objectives:

- id
- objective_type
- points_needed_to_cross

Level_Obejectives_Level_Relation:

- id
- level_tables_id
- level_objectives_id

`Schema 2:`

Levels_Table=>

- id
- group_id
- reward_given
- level

Level_Objectives:

- id
- objective_type
- points_needed_to_cross
- level_id

Each group has a different set of levels with same level having different objectives in different groups, so in the 2nd schema, the objectives are repeated for different level_id.

Under this scenario, which form of normalization is better given the traffic I get on the platform. Please help me how to evaluate this.

Comment: Your schemas are different, it's not just normalization.  The first one is a many-many relationship, the second a one-many.  As such, the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Paddy Yes I understand that, but I am confused how to evaluate the which is a better design out of these two. Any procedure that I should follow should be helpful.

Comment: Is "level" something important to the question?  Or is it related to hierarchy?  Please either remove "level" throughout, or clarify what it means.

Comment: To judge whether you have "over-normalized", we need to see the `SELECTs`.

Comment: I can see that your many:many relation table is inefficient.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to evaluate how often a Objectives can be associated to multiple level.
If the answer is never and you are sure 100% about that, then the schema 2 is the best one.
Otherwise, I think it's better to go with schema 1.

Comment: so my functional requirement states that I can have multiple objectives belonging to one level. Schema 1 gives me an edge in analysing and structuring data, but how should I check which would give the best user experience.

Comment: what do you mean by user experience?